# Unwanted vertical space at top of page before subsection heading

Tags: spacing, macros, sectioning, sections-paragraphs

I have been using LaTeX for a while now, but I am very new to defining my own commands in the preamble.  I am working on my thesis, and I'm using a custom `.cls` file which has been passed down by other grad students over the years.

When I start a new subsection, there is a certain amount of vertical space required between the preceding paragraph and the subsection heading.  This works great if the subsection starts in the middle of a page, but when a subsection starts at the top of the page there is unwanted vertical space.  I can manually go through and add `\vspace*{-<some distance>}` before certain instances of `\subsection{<title>}` to fix this problem, but I'd prefer to either write a new command or edit the subsection definition in the `.cls` file so that the vertical space is automatically removed if the subsection starts on a new page.

Thanks in advance!

---

EDIT 10/9/15 at 3:40 pm CDT
Here's how subsections are defined in the custom .cls.  Sorry for not including it originally

```
\renewcommand\subsection{\secdef\@subsection\@ssubsection}

\def\@subsection[#1]#2{\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
                       \refstepcounter{subsection}%

\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{\protect\numberline{\thesubsection .}\uppercase{#1}}%
                     \fi
                     \@makesubsectionhead{#1}
                     }

\def\@ssubsection[#1]#2{\@makessubsectionhead{#1}}

\def\@makesubsectionhead#1{\vspace*{\baselineskip}%
           {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \bfseries 
            \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
              \ifnum\c@inappendix=0\@chapapp\space\fi\thesubsection .\space
            \fi
             \uppercase{#1}\par\nobreak           
             }}
\def\@makessubsectionhead#1{\vspace*{\baselineskip}%
\bfseries  \uppercase{#1}\par\nobreak   
             }
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. This doesn't happen in the standard classes, and we would need to see this custom `.cls` to be able to say anything about how to edit it.

Comment: if you don't show any code, not really possible to help

Comment: Such `inherited` templates are most times ... well ... bad

Comment: I added an edit.  Sorry for not including code originally -- this is my first post on stackexchange :)

Comment: replace `\vspace*{\baselineskip}` with `\vspace{\baselineskip}`

Comment: That solved the problem, thanks!  I was just reading about the difference between \vspace and \vspace* and came to the same conclusion.

Comment: @JSchaefer -- kudos for reading the documentation.  more people should do that.

Comment: what is the intention of this redefinition? It looks like it removes several features that the standard headings worry about, you could get a page break between the table of contents line being written and the heading (so the toc entry could point one page too early) it disables the secnumdepth feature,  it doesn't use the standard \@afterheading mechanism to prevent page breaks within one line of the heading and suppress indentation

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Non-suppression of indentation in the next paragraph may be considered a feature. But there are, of course, ways of achieving that without the other effects.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Do you want to take any action here?

Comment: @Johannes_B not really